# trying to install emailrelay on CentOS Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64

Tags: yum, dependencies

I've got some software on a Windows box that I need to send email from. It isn't smart enough to talk to anything other than a non-encrypted SMTP server, though, so I had the bright idea(!) to sit emailrelay between this windows program and Gmail, so that I can use my Gmail account (with its requirement for TLS etc...). Trying to install on my Linux server and getting this - shouldn't yum be resolving these dependencies and installing them for me? Does it mean it can't?

thanks

```
Examining download.rpm: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
Marking download.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emailrelay.x86_64 0:2.2-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emailrelay.x86_64 0:2.2-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64
---> Package openssl11-libs.x86_64 1:1.1.1c-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64 (/rownload)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
Error: Package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64 (/rownload)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64 (/rownload)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit)
Error: Package: emailrelay-2.2-1.x86_64 (/rownload)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are describing using the `postfix` package already available on CentOS. No need to rely on a questionable RPM on sourceforge.

There are dozens of guides on setting up postfix to use smarthost relay host through gmail.  [Here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/) is a guide that has all the steps.

Once that is set up, you will need to open up the firewall for the windows host to talk to port 25 on the CentOS server.

Comment: hmmm,  I've previously already setup my Linux server to be able to send email using Gmail - this works fine - I did a test email to confirm it and it works just fine. What I'm trying to do is allow my WINDOWS machine to use the Linux server as a relay ultimately to Gmail. I'll see if I can find a guide that covers this. Thank you for putting me on much the right track! :-)

Comment: Setting up a postfix system to relay from certain IPs/subsets is part of the basic config, too: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#relay_from

Answer (score 0):

You need the version of the `libstdc++.so` library that contains a minimum of `GLIBCXX 3.4.20` and `CXXABI_1.3.8`.

From the kernel version, you are using CentOS 7 where the version of `libtsdc++.so` isn't recent enough.

You can see this with the command:

```
strings -d /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -Ei '^glibcxx|^cxxabi'
```

You'll see that what you have includes a maximum of 3.4.19 and 1.3.7 respectively because CentOS 7 has `GCC 4.8.5` which was released on June 23 2015.

I would recommend GCC 8 which which is far more recent and includes the version of `libstdc++.so` that you need. You'll have to compile it from source and add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH then compile `emailrelay` from source as the RPM will be looking for the package containing the more recent version to be installed on your system  which isn't possible due to conflicts.